# What permission is for Graph API /me object address property. Is that disabled for privacy?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Graph API returns null for /me object address property. I cannot find permission for address. What permission is for user current address? Is address always inaccessible because of privacy issue? Thanks

Comment: You mean the user’s address as in place of residence? No, that’s not available via API any more.

Comment: Yes, as `location` similar to what PayPal provides for online shopping/payment. That is what I suspected based on my research and privacy concerns raised in posts 2 years ago. Surprisingly, Graph API still recognizes `address` as a valid field of `me` object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a user as logged in, you can call /me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN and it will return at least basic information about the user. No special permissions needed.

One important thing is that the access_token must be tied to a user (aka - received after a user login). If you simply get an access_token for the application (using `client_credentials`), then `/me` would not be valid endpoint. You can find out by running the access_token through the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

If you don't use an `access_token`, or you use an `acces_token` that is not tied to a person (like the scenario listed), you'll get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

So `/me` should never return `null`. There's always a json response of some sort. If this did not help then post that response in a comment to this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant permission in my original question when I wrote "access token". That is true /me never returns null, but when you run /me?fields=name,address,email,location in Graph API Explorer, it will always return non-null values for name and location and null for address. Email requires explicit email permission to return non-null value. What permission does address require to return non-null value? Note, I have address added to my profile Contact.

Comment: Ah. You want `user_location` and/or `user_hometown`. Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/

Comment: BTW, an exact address is not available. City is.

Comment: BTW, [API Reference › FQL › user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) shows `current_address` and `current_location` available along with `street`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `zip`, etc., but they apparently are not. Confusing, the least to say. Thanks anyway.